# IntelliJ IDEA - line wrapping without breaking in the middle of a method call

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

Is there an option in IDEA to stop the code formatter (for Java code) from breaking long lines at inappropriate places, specifically I am finding that it will place the line break between a method call and its opening bracket, e.g.

```
Collection<Thing> things = Arrays.asList(Something.getThings("Foo", foo.bar()), x, y, z);
```

becomes:

```
Collection<Thing> things = Arrays.asList(Something.getThings("Foo", foo.bar
        ()), x, y, z);
```

if it happens to cross the line length boundary.

I know I could refactor this particular code sample to not have the method call inline, but as a more general question can IDEA be configured to be smarter at placing the line break?  Ideally I would rather this gets split to:

```
Collection<Thing> things = Arrays.asList(Something.getThings("Foo", 
        foo.bar()), x, y, z);
```

Comment: It's a bug, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach a sample file to reproduce with your code style (File | Export Settings).

Comment: As of my experience, small code style and usability problems rarely get any attention after reporting. So I stopped wasting my time reporting those. I wish IDEA had many more code style options regarding line break and indentation.

Comment: I've raised it with them and I'll see what comes back: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173635

Comment: For now I can manually add the line break where I want and set the option to retain existing line breaks on formatting.